# How do you view segment-offset memory addresses in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, x86, disassembly, memory-segmentation

I'm debugging some code from the disassembly (no source code is available), and there a number of instructions accessing data via the `ds` segment register, e.g. something like this:

```
66 3B 05 8A B1 43 00 cmp         ax,word ptr ds:[43B18Ah]
```

How do you get the Visual Studio debugger to tell you the offset of the `ds` segment register so that I can inspect the memory this is referring to?  The Watch window does not seem to accept expressions like `ds:[0x43B18A]` or variants; it will tell me that `ds` is 0, but that doesn't tell me what segment 0's offset is.

Is there some special syntax for this, or is this something that VS just can't do?  Would I have better luck with another debugger, such as WinDbg or ntsd?

Comment: You will have better luck with WinDbg, Olly, or PE Explorer or even IDA Pro...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quirk of the disassembler built into Visual Studio.  It is superfluous, the DS register is the default.  Just ignore it, on Windows the DS, CS and ES registers are set to the same value.  A protected mode selector.  And the same value used by the Memory window.  Just omit the ds: prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of something so simple.  I know the segment registers are used for DLL-related stuff, so I thought it might be pointing off into the data segment of a DLL or something.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: all segments except FS and/or GS have a base of `0`.  Not only the same value, but a simple flat memory model where the offset part of the address is the only non-zero part.  Thread-local storage using a `gs:` segment base is the only time you should be wondering about where in linear virtual address space the access actually happened, under a normal mainstream OS like Windows.